# No thread-bound request found only when throws a runtime exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-cloud

I need to use Request Scope on my code to get and use Authorization on JWT token, each request have an individual token and each request need an isolated validation. When any request process without any error, all works fine, but if the application throws any runtime exception, BadRequestException for example, the response broke with: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found

I'm using a Spring cloud environment with Ribbon, Feign and Hystrix.

Here the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implementation:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(enviroment, jwtAuthenticationService, authScope),
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();

        http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();

    }
```

My before filter

```
    package br.com.qisi.twoface.configuration.security.jwt;

    import br.com.qisi.twoface.authorization.model.Authorization;
    import br.com.qisi.twoface.configuration.security.AuthRequestScope;
    import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
    import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
    import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
    import org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean;

    import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import java.io.IOException;

    public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

        private String enviroment;
        private JWTAuthenticationService jwtAuthenticationService;
        private AuthRequestScope authRequestScope;

        public JWTAuthenticationFilter(String enviroment,
                                                                    JWTAuthenticationService jwtAuthenticationService,
                                                                    AuthRequestScope authRequestScope) {
            this.enviroment = enviroment;
            this.jwtAuthenticationService = jwtAuthenticationService;
            this.authRequestScope = authRequestScope;
        }

        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                throws IOException, ServletException {

            Claims jwtClaims = this.jwtAuthenticationService.getJWTClaims((HttpServletRequest) request);

            try {
                Authorization authorization = this.jwtAuthenticationService.checkJWT(enviroment, jwtClaims);
                this.authRequestScope.setAuthorization(authorization);
            } catch (UnauthorizedException ex){
                ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendError(401, ex.getMessage());
                return;
            }

            Authentication authentication = this.jwtAuthenticationService.getAuthentication(jwtClaims);

            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
```

Error Stack trace

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.authScope': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:365) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:672) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at br.com.qisi.twoface.configuration.security.AuthScope$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bf5257a6.setAuthorization(<generated>) ~[classes!/:0.0.1]
    at br.com.qisi.twoface.configuration.security.jwt.JWTAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(JWTAuthenticationFilter.java:40) ~[classes!/:0.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:394) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:253) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:175) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:791) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]

    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.AbstractRequestAttributesScope.get(AbstractRequestAttributesScope.java:42) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:353) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    2019-01-19 14:41:51.395 ERROR 1 --- [nio-9093-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost] : Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.authScope': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:365) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:672) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at br.com.qisi.twoface.configuration.security.AuthScope$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bf5257a6.setAuthorization(<generated>) ~[classes!/:0.0.1]
    at br.com.qisi.twoface.configuration.security.jwt.JWTAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(JWTAuthenticationFilter.java:40) ~[classes!/:0.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:394) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:253) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:175) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:791) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar!/:9.0.13]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.AbstractRequestAttributesScope.get(AbstractRequestAttributesScope.java:42) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:353) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
```

I just want to understand why the error only happens when an exception is thrown.
 It seems that when the error happens the transaction with the answer goes back through the filter. But I don't know how to fix this behavior.

Comment: Why do you need a request scoped bean? You have already the request to use?

Comment: I need request scope to use the Claim inside my token in other services on the application, otherwise I will need to pass the header claims under all controllers to services.

Comment: You could save that information in your request object and get it in your services. Or you could save it in your authentication object as a additional custom value.

Comment: With this approach, I probably will face concurrence problems because service is a singleton component.

Comment: You couldn't have concurrence problems because your request and your authentication exists only in one thread.

Comment: But if I set the Request in a service class attribute for some A request and at the same time a set again the class attribute for some B request, this approach I will overwrite the current request in all application right?

Comment: You didn't overwrite anything. The authentication object is saved at login in by Spring Security. The request is created with every request by your container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @dur comments I changed my code to use SecurityContextHolder and get the current thread context authorization.

My component now:

```
    @Component
    public class AuthRequestInfo {

        private AuthorizationService authorizationService;

        public AuthRequestInfo(AuthorizationService authorizationService) {
            this.authorizationService = authorizationService;
        }

        public Authorization getAuthorization(){
            Claims claims = (Claims)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
            String key = claims.get(KEY_CLAIM).toString();
            return this.authorizationService.findByExampleOptional(Authorization.builder().key(key).build())
                    .orElseThrow(new UnauthorizedException(INVALID_TWOFACE_AUTHORIZATION_HEADER));
        }

    }
```

The SecurityContextHolder authentication was setted on GenericFilterBean. Now I don't have problems.